# Google PageSpeed - Eliminate render-blocking CSS

Tags: css, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I'm trying to get 100/100 mark at Google PageSpeed. I currently have 91/100 and there is only one possible optimalization - render-blocking CSS.

I put some most important CSS in the `<style>` tag in the `<head>`, [as recommended](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) . However, I have ~500 lines .css file with the rest CSS, that makes the website fancy. I tried moving the `<link/>` after the `</body>` or the `</html>` tag, so it's not blocking anything, but, when I load the page even on a fast internet connection, I first see just a plain, not very fancy text, and then it changes to what I want as the css loads, but PageSpeed is still giving me only 91 points because of this.

I also have mod-pagespeed installed on my Apache2 server.

What is the proper way to insert this CSS so Google will be fine with it?

Comment: You are fine, it doesn't affect anything. :) I also have tried many a times to reach 100/100 but it seems google doesn't want it to happen. You first get normal text then the fancy text as when the page loads it hasn't yet loaded the fancy css, but when it loads you get your fancy text.

Comment: There is really no need for 100% score, 91 is more than good enough. Please read this link for all the information you need: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery?hl=en

Comment: Google PageSpeed is the easiest to get 100/100.  I'd need a URL or a waterfall image.  All CSS and fonts must be loaded before any JavaScript.  Use http://www.webpagetest.org/ to see the waterfall.